# How do you click on an element with text and copy the clipboard value in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I have a markup where when I click on a div I get some value to the clipboard.

```html
<div class="group">
    <div class="label_wrapper">
        <span class="icon icon-copy"></span>
        <p class="label">Copy Address</p>
    </div>
    <div class="address"><Some value...></div>
</div>
```

```js
async function saveCopiedText(page) {
    const buttons = await page.$$('.group');

    for (const button of buttons) {
        const buttonText = await button.evaluate((el) =>
            el.textContent.includes('Copy Address'),
        );

        if (buttonText) {
            await button.click();

            const copiedText = await page.evaluate(() =>
                navigator.clipboard.readText(),
            );

            console.log(copiedText); // Is not working
        }
    }
}
```

As a result of performing options on clicks, there is no output.

The loop in this code is necessary in order to iterate on all the buttons found on the pages.

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). Can you provide a website you're manipulating and describe why you need to achieve whatever result you're trying to achieve using this rather roundabout method? If your goal is to get "Some value...", I'd scrape that directly without the clipboard: `await page.$$eval(".group", els => els.map(el => el.querySelector(".address").textContent)));`. This skips a good deal of complexity, messing with clicking, element handles and the clipboard, all of which are "last resort" fallbacks.

Comment: At the moment, I'm not trying to interact with any site. However, the fact is that you need to interact with the clipboard, because when you click on the button, the data will get into the clipboard, and will not be displayed in the external UI in any way assumes that the data is only partially visible. Let it be some kind of hash (I don't know) :D foo$...#1bar (The part that is hidden... will never be visible)

Comment: Thanks, that helps motivate why you need to click on it. I'll look into it as soon as I can, although I suspect there may be a fundamental block here--Puppeteer may not have access to the clipboard. The data has to get to the client's browser somehow/somewhere, though, so I'd suggest checking the network tab to find the data you want rather than assuming you must click the button and operate through the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I also check the "network" tab, and nothing happens in it (otherwise I probably wouldn't do it), the generation \ encryption and parsing of the value comes directly from JavaScript) and even more precisely, react (I see this from the browser plugin)